# Passing values within a multi-step form using Laravel 8 and Livewire 2.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a multi-step form where a user can add cars to their profile.  The first step is where the car is created and the relationship is established between the `user` and `usercar`.  The first step works as it should, but it doesn't establish and or retain a connection to the `usercar` in subsequent steps.  I know I am missing an obvious step of hydration or session code, but this is new territory for me.

**AddUserCar.php**

```
...
class AddUserCar extends Component
{
    public $showAnotherModel = false;

    // Steps
    public $totalSteps = 8;
    public $step = 1;
    // User
    public $super;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;
    public $status = 1;
    public $role = 'Driver';
    // Usercar
    public $car_id;
    public $calc_date;
    // Form Function
    public $car_year;

    //public $cars;
    //public $modelId;

    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        if(session()->has('tenant_id')) {
            $this->super = false;
        } else {
            $this->super = true;
            $this->tenants = Tenant::all()->pluck('first_name', 'id')->toArray();
        }

        $this->carYears = Car::all()
            ->unique('start_year')
            ->sortByDesc('start_year');

        $this->carModels = Car::all()
            ->unique('start_year')
            ->sortByDesc('start_year');

        $this->getModels();
    }

    ...

    public function moveAhead()
    {

        if($this->step == 1) {

            Usercar::create([
                'car_id' => $this->car_id,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'tenant_id' => Auth::user()->tenant_id,
                'calc_date' => now()->format('m-d-Y'),
            ]);
            dd($this->calc_date); // this produces an error
            
            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }

        if($this->step == 2) {
            // Step Code
            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }

        if($this->step == 3) {
            // Step Code

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }
        if($this->step == 4) {
            // Step Code

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }
        if($this->step == 5) {
            // Step Code

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }
        if($this->step == 6) {
            // Step Code

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }
        if($this->step == 7) {
            // Step Code

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }

        if($this->step == 8) {
            // Step Code

            redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        //Increase Step
        $this->step += 1;
        $this->_validateStep();
    }

    public function moveBack()
    {
        $this->step -= 1;
        $this->_validateStep();
    }

    private function _validateStep()
    {
        if ($this->step < 1) {
            $this->step = 1;
        }

        if ($this->step > $this->totalSteps) {
            $this->step = $this->totalSteps;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.add-user-car',
        ['pageTitle' => 'Add Driver Car']);
    }
}
```

Comment: create a public property and get the created model of Usercar like $this->usercarCreated = Usercar::create...

Comment: @Prospero that worked.  Thank you!